# Python server is not replying back with answer to message sent by client

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python math server . The user (Client) can send messages to the server containing the operands and operator . The server shall receive it and calculate it and send the results back . However my server is not sending back the results for some reason

This is my client.py file

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5000

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect((host,port))
r = "no"

while r != "exit":
    op1 = input('enter operand 1:')
    op2 = input('enter operand 2:')
    op  = input('enter operator:')

    client_socket.send(op1.encode())
    client_socket.send(op2.encode())
    client_socket.send(op.encode())

    result = client_socket.recv(1024).decode();
    print("answer:",result)

    r=input("enter exit to stop:")

client_socket.close()
```

And this is my server.py file

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind((host,port))
server_socket.listen(1)
conn , address = server_socket.accept()

while True:
    op1 = conn.recv(1024).decode()

    if not op1:
        break;

    op2 = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    op = conn.recv(1024).decode()


    if op == '+':
        message = int(op1) + int(op2)

    elif op =='-':
        message = int(op1) - int(op2)

    elif op =='*':
        message = int(op1) * int(op2)

    else : message = int(op1) / int(op2)

    conn.send(message.encode())

server_socket.close()
```

Both the files are running successfully without any errors , however the server is not returning any result back to the client

Comment: Does client listening to a port? I don't see this in code, where is server returning the result to?

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ
His client does `.recv()` I believe, that's enough to receive response from server. Maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @tom-jonh try following this guide and make work echo client and server: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: @ViacheslavShalamov on which port? both of them are 5000?

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ The client port is automatically assigned. The port 5000 on the client side is used to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to bind a ip to your host if you use both program on your computer bind 127.0.0.1
and in socket.socket you have to tell which kind of socket you using 
something like

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

and you can send 1 thing in one go so wrap all of you data in one variable send it to server and then split it again and finally you message back to client and it is not string it is int and you cant encode it so change you message variable to str

Comment: `socket.socket()` defaults to `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`

Comment: tnx i didnt know that i always define the socket type on it, and with the answer i send , i get the program to work

Comment: @hamzeh_pm the socket.socket() function uses those by parameters by default when nothing is mentioned in the round brackets

Answer (score 0):

i change your code little bit 
server code

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen()
conn , address = server_socket.accept()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    if not data:
        break;

    if data.find('+') != -1:
        list_data = data.split('+')
        op1 = list_data[0]
        op2 = list_data[1]
        op = '+'

    if data.find('*') != -1:
        list_data = data.split('*')
        op1 = list_data[0]
        op2 = list_data[1]
        op = '*'

    if data.find('-') != -1:
        list_data = data.split('_')
        op1 = list_data[0]
        op2 = list_data[1]
        op = '-'

    if data.find('/') != -1:
        list_data = data.split('/')
        op1 = list_data[0]
        op2 = list_data[1]
        op = '/'

    if op == '+':
        message = int(op1) + int(op2)

    elif op =='-':
        message = int(op1) - int(op2)

    elif op =='*':
        message = int(op1) * int(op2)

    else : message = int(op1) / int(op2)

    conn.send(str(message).encode())

server_socket.close()
```

client code

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect((host,port))
r = "no"

while r != "exit":
    op1 = input('enter operand 1:')
    op2 = input('enter operand 2:')
    op  = input('enter operator:')

    data = op1 + op + op2
    client_socket.sendall(data.encode())

    result = client_socket.recv(1024).decode();
    print("answer:",result)

    r=input("enter exit to stop:")

client_socket.close()
```